# Java ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException MOOC Helsinki - where is the mistake in my code?

Tags: java

I've been searching for an answer, but without any results. I know that this exception means that I'm trying to reach nonexistent array element, but I just can't see it.

It's excercise 104 from MOOC Helsinki, you can read it here

http://mooc.cs.helsinki.fi/programming-part1/material-2013/week-6?noredirect=1

I'm supposed to create sorting algorithm by creating five methods one after another. I've created first four, but things go south with the final one. I have no idea whether it's just matter of changing a single character, or the whole construction is flawed.

I would be grateful for help, feel free to comment on my code, but if it's possible do not overwrite the whole thing, I don't want solving it for me, just some hints and help.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {

    public static int smallest(int[] array) {
        int result = array[0];
        int position = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < (array.length); i++) {
            if (result > array[i]) {
                result = array[i];
                position = i;
            }
        }
        return result;

    }

    public static int indexOfTheSmallest(int[] array) {
        int result = array[0];
        int position = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < (array.length); i++) {
            if (result > array[i]) {
                result = array[i];
                position = i;
            }
        }
        return position;
    }

    public static int indexOfTheSmallestStartingFrom(int[] array, int index) {
        int result = array[index];
        int position = 0;
        for (int i = index; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (result > array[i]) {
                result = array[i];
                position = i;
            }
        }
        return position;
    }

    public static void swap(int[] array, int index1, int index2) {
        int a = array[index1];
        int b = array[index2];

        array[index1] = b;
        array[index2] = a;
    }

    public static void sort(int[] array) {
        int temp;
        for (int x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
            temp = indexOfTheSmallestStartingFrom(array, x);
            swap(array, array[x], temp);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] values = {8, 3, 7, 9, 1, 2, 4};
        sort(values);
    }
}
```

Comment: `swap(array, array[x], temp);` The 2nd param looks like a problem.

Comment: What do you think `indexOfTheSmallestStartingFrom()` returns when the smallest element in the specified range is the one at the starting index?

Comment: This would be a good time to learn about writing unit tests.

Comment: I changed ' indexOfTheSmallestStartingFrom() ' and set 'position = index', but I keep getting the same mistake.

Answer (score 0):

change swap(array, array[x], temp); to
swap(array, x, temp);

Comment: Thanks, I guess I was too blind to spot this after two hours searching this code for a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out,

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {

    public static int smallest(int[] array) {
        int result = array[0];
        int position = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < (array.length); i++) {
            if (result > array[i]) {
                result = array[i];
                position = i;
            }
        }
        return result;

    }

    public static int indexOfTheSmallest(int[] array) {
        int result = array[0];
        int position = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < (array.length); i++) {
            if (result > array[i]) {
                result = array[i];
                position = i;
            }
        }
        return position;
    }

    public static int indexOfTheSmallestStartingFrom(int[] array, int index) {
        int result = array[index];
        int position = 0;
        for (int i = index; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (result > array[i]) {
                result = array[i];
                position = i;
            }
        }
        return position;
    }

    public static void swap( int index1, int index2) {
        int a = array[index1];
        int b = array[index2];

        array[index1] = b;
        array[index2] = a;
    }

    public static void sort() {
        int temp;
        for (int x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
            temp = indexOfTheSmallestStartingFrom(array, x);
            swap( x, temp);
        }
    }
    static int [] array= {8, 3, 7, 9, 1, 2, 4};

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        sort();
    }
}
```

`swap` function was making changes but they weren't reflected because you were using **pass-by-value**.

I haven't touched the algorithm because the output is not as expected.